# When Appium start, how can I click the "Start Server" button automatically?

Tags: javascript, appium

I do not know how control the JavaScript of index file.

This is main page of Appium. I want to start Appium automatically, not manually click the start button. But another JavaScript file has this button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Appium</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.afc771a2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.global.bd8b6ea1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="github-gist-theme.global.9acb3836.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="renderer.e31bb0bc.css">
</head>
<body> 
<div id="root"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="renderer.e31bb0bc.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

How can I start automatically the Appium server not manually?

[image]

Maybe I change some code index.html I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this for automated testing. You may want to use a different, more terminal oriented bundle of Appium (for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium) and automate it with a tool like Jenkins.

As an example with the node version:

- Download and install Nodejs if you don't have it
- Open Terminal and type `npm i -g appium` and press enter
- type `appium` to start server without GUI

You can than compose a shell script that calls `appium` to start server with default values.

Comment: Yes, Excatly I do your suggestion. The Script which is made on the Appium.exe is correctly working on the Appuim.exe but it has an error on the node.js version appium.
I use Korean on the Script after install node js, the Korean is now shown on the command line. Do you have a idea change appium script?

Comment: I checked once again Node.js using Python2 but windows' appium and my computer use python3. So it does not work properlly. The language problem is also same. Do you have any idea change the Appium's index.html?

Comment: @Yun-HoJang I suggest you ask this as a new question:  "The Script which is made on the Appium.exe is correctly working on the Appuim.exe but it has an error on the node.js version appium." and give code examples and error messages.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. It works pretty well but one computer has two version python is not suitable. After one month, one of them disappear. And all of my program are for suitable for Python3. So automation program replace "python" to "python3". Do you have another idea for me?

Comment: @Yun-HoJang, are you still working with Appium.exe, or did you change to appium.js?

Comment: still working with Appium.exe V10.0. It is easy to change the index.html but can not upgrade. Another computer test appium.js. This computer is the same as the computer with Appium.exe V10.0.  I think Js version can not have same ability as the Appium.exe When I test all the script, only Js version failed it.

Comment: @Yun-HoJang: Appium.exe V10.0 uses an older version of appium.js to run tests. You can see it under https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/blob/62257dc78097c399fb9a823f649655f4022f400b/package.json Where it is declared as "appium": "^1.10.0".

You can use NPM to download this version of appium.js